# Performing spark streaming on json message from kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am getting json message from kafka and converting it into key,pair value.
This is my kafka producer code.

```
val r = scala.util.Random
      for( a <- 1 to 100){
   var id1=s"ST_${r.nextInt(50)}"
   val date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
   val d = new Date()
   val dateString = date.format(d)
   val date1=date.toString
   val temp=r.nextInt(90)
   val press=r.nextInt(70)
   val hum=r.nextInt(30)
   var first= new data(id1,dateString,temp,press,hum)


 implicit val writes = Json.writes[data]
   val jsonString = Json.toJson(first).toString

   val record = new ProducerRecord(TOPIC, "key", jsonString)

   producer.send(record)
   Thread.sleep(5000)
```

For spark consumer I am using

```
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("test1" -> 5))
```

to read json message and convert it into key pair value.

My output is like this

(key,{"id":"ST_44","date":"2018-02-23 23:56:12","temp":76,"pressure":40,"humidity":29})

(key,{"id":"ST_49","date":"2018-02-23 23:56:14","temp":36,"pressure":60,"humidity":22})

I want to do some operation like getting station with minimum value etc but as I am new to spark I am totally lost. I tried using reducebykey and filter functions but getting error. If anyone can help please.

Comment: It would help if you tell us what have you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: for example i want to use it pairs.filter{case (key, value) => value.length < 20} but here my value has different values and i want to find minimum temperature from all json messages.